# Moveable grid in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dynamic, grid

I am working on a moveable grid system for my voxel game, I implemented most of it, but I keep getting stuck at making the actual Move function. This is the code without the Move function implemented:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Grid<T>
{
    private T[] data;
    public Vector3Int position;
    public Vector3Int size;
    public int iSize;

    public Grid(Vector3Int size)
    {
        this.position = new Vector3Int(0, 0, 0);
        this.size = size;
        this.iSize = size.x * size.y * size.z;
        this.data = new T[size.x * size.y * size.z];
    }

    public T this[int x, int y, int z]
    {
        get
        {
            Vector3Int position = new Vector3Int(x, y, z);
            if (!IsValidIndex(position - this.position))
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Invalid position");
            }

            Vector3Int positionRelative = PositionToRelative(position);
            return this.data[VectorToIndex(positionRelative)];
        }
        set
        {
            Vector3Int position = new Vector3Int(x, y, z);
            if (!IsValidIndex(position - this.position))
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Invalid position");
            }

            Vector3Int positionRelative = PositionToRelative(position);
            this.data[VectorToIndex(positionRelative)] = value;
        }
    }

    public void Move(Vector3Int newPosition)
    {
        Vector3Int offset = PositionToRelative(newPosition);
        T[] newData = new T[data.Length];

        this.data = newData;
        this.position = newPosition;
    }

    private bool IsPositionInRange(Vector3Int position, Vector3Int start, Vector3Int end)
    {
        int minX = Mathf.Min(start.x, end.x);
        int maxX = Mathf.Max(start.x, end.x);
        int minY = Mathf.Min(start.y, end.y);
        int maxY = Mathf.Max(start.y, end.y);
        int minZ = Mathf.Min(start.z, end.z);
        int maxZ = Mathf.Max(start.z, end.z);
        return position.x >= minX
            && position.x <= maxX
            && position.y >= minY
            && position.y <= maxY
            && position.z >= minZ
            && position.z <= maxZ;
    }

    private Vector3Int PositionToRelative(Vector3Int position)
    {
        return position - this.position;
    }

    private bool IsValidIndex(Vector3Int position)
    {
        int index = VectorToIndex(position);

        return index >= 0 && index < this.iSize;
    }

    private bool IsValidIndex(int index)
    {
        return index >= 0 && index < this.iSize;
    }

    private int VectorToIndex(Vector3Int position)
    {
        return position.x + this.size.x * (position.y + this.size.y * position.z);
    }
}
```

This is the code Im using to test it:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Tester : MonoBehaviour
{
    void PrintMatrix<T>(Grid<T> grid)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < grid.size.x; x++)
        {
            string output = "\n";

            for (int y = 0; y < grid.size.y; y++)
            {
                Vector3Int position = new Vector3Int(x, y, 0) + grid.position;
                output += grid[position.x, position.y, position.z];

                if (y < grid.size.y - 1)
                {
                    output += " ";
                }
            }

            Debug.Log(output);
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        Vector3Int size = new Vector3Int(4, 4, 1);
        Grid<int> grid = new Grid<int>(size);

        for (int x = 0; x < size.x; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < size.y; y++)
            {
                grid[x, y, 0] = x + size.y * y + 1;
            }
        }

        PrintMatrix<int>(grid);

        Debug.Log("-------- Amogus ------------");

        grid.Move(new Vector3Int(-1, 0, 0));

        PrintMatrix<int>(grid);
    }

    void Update() { }
}
```

The example shifts the grid in the left.

First time it logs the matrix correctly:

1 5 9 13

2 6 10 14

3 7 11 15

4 8 12 16

However the second time its incorrect.
What it prints with the current move function:

What it's supposed to print:

0 1 5 9

0 2 6 10

0 3 7 11

0 4 8 12

What it prints:

2 6 10 14

3 7 11 15

4 8 12 16

0 9 13 0

I've tried this Move function, but its not working, I could not figure out how to get good startPosition and endPosition.

```cs
    public void Move(Vector3Int position)
    {
        T[] newData = new T[data.Length];
        Vector3Int positionRelative = PositionToRelative(position);

        Vector3Int startPosition = new Vector3Int(
            positionRelative.x >= 0 ? positionRelative.x : this.size.x + positionRelative.x,
            positionRelative.y >= 0 ? positionRelative.y : this.size.y + positionRelative.y,
            positionRelative.z >= 0 ? positionRelative.z : this.size.z + positionRelative.z
        );
        Vector3Int endPosition = new Vector3Int(
            positionRelative.x < 0 ? this.size.x : positionRelative.x,
            positionRelative.y < 0 ? this.size.y : positionRelative.y,
            positionRelative.z < 0 ? this.size.z : positionRelative.z
        );

        Debug.Log(positionRelative + " " + startPosition + " " + endPosition);

        for (int x = 0; x < size.x; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < size.y; y++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < size.z; z++)
                {
                    Vector3Int currentPosition = new Vector3Int(x, y, z);
                    int index = VectorToIndex(currentPosition);
                    int translationIndex = VectorToIndex(currentPosition - positionRelative);

                    if (
                        IsPositionInRange(currentPosition, startPosition, endPosition)
                        || !IsValidIndex(translationIndex)
                    )
                    {
                        newData[index] = default(T);
                        continue;
                    }

                    newData[index] = data[translationIndex];
                }
            }
        }

        this.position = position;
        data = newData;
    }
```

[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0zXw.jpg)

The first grid with position 0, 0, 0 shows how a 2x2 part of it would look like, and the second grid with position -1, 0, 0 shows how a 2x2 part of it should look shifted, and under them are the small 2x2 grids shown. THe one which is 0 6 0 7 is how it should look in code, 0 because the code cannot guess that its supposed to be 2 and 3.

Comment: its not entirely clear what your numbers are, so for the move, you seem to expect the numbers to mvoe one column to the left and for the right hand ones to become 0.  I assume 0 is dont do anything so, in short your grid becomes one column short. Perhaps if you think of it in that manner rather than the complexities of what you have  so if x is across and y upm x[0]=x[1] etc, and when it gets to the end, and there is no more, set it to zero.. then perhaps that will be more efficient too

Comment: I want to shift it one in the left. Because it is shifted, one column is blank, so it defaults to default(T), which is 0 for ints. Maybe I got it wrong and the first column is supposed to be blank instead of the last, but I've made some drawings on paper on how its supposed to look like. Ill edit the post and send the drawings.

Comment: Could you tell us how exactly you initialized the array? like what are your `size` and how do the values in the `data` look like initially?

Comment: I've initialized the array in the test code I provided, and I show the output shortly after

Comment: @Bloxxy213 ah fair enough didn't catch that!

Comment: Would something speak against wrap around the indices? In general I think it is iterating wrong through it at least assuming you want to lay out X left to right and Y top to bottom ... your `what it prints` actually is what I would expect since currently your "X" values are layed out top to bottom so everything is shifted 1 up ... only he bottom `0 9 13 0` seems off

Comment: +X is right, -X is left, +Y is up, -Y is down, -Z is behind, +Z is in front, like normal Vectors

Comment: not the way you print no ... You are printing one line for each X (=> X is top to bottom) and print 4 Y values in each line (=> Y is left to right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest issue seems to be your `PrintMatrix`.

It prints the values the following way

- For each X prints a line

  => X goes top to bottom
- In each line prints 4 consecutive Y values

  => Y goes left to right

Basically your `What it prints` is closer to what I would expect as it correctl shifts everything one step upwards (negative X direction)

It should probably rather be e.g.

```
public void PrintMatrix(Grid<T> grid)
{
    var output = new StringBuilder();

    for (var y = 0; y < grid.size.y; y++)
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < grid.size.x; x++)
        {
            var value = grid[x, y, 0];
            if(value < 10) output.Append(' ')
            output.Append(value);

            output.Append(' ');
        }

        output.Append('\n');
    }

    Debug.Log(output.ToString());
}
```

which would print out a line for each Y (=> top to bottom) and then within the line X (=> left to right).

---

Actually I would probably go for a wrap-around of the indices and have something like e.g.

```
private int VectorToIndex(Vector3Int index) => VectorToIndex(index.x, index.y, index.z);

private int VectorToIndex(int x, int y, int z)
{
    x = x.WrapAround(size.x);
    y = y.WrapAround(size.y);
    z = z.WrapAround(size.z);

    return x + size.x * (y + size.y * z);
}
```

with extension method

```
public static class IntExtensions
{
    public static int WrapAround(this int value, int maxValue)
    {
        return ((value % maxValue) + maxValue) % maxValue;
    }
}
```

for wrapping the index at the borders

=>

first print

```
1  2   3  4 
5  6   7  8 
9  10 11 12 
13 14 15 16
```

print after moving (-1 ,0 ,0)

```
 2  3  4  1 
 6  7  8  5 
10 11 12  9 
14 15 16 13
```

=> all values shifted one to the left (= negative X direction)

---

And just a sidenote you know you can also directly use the vector as indexer and do

```
public T this[Vector3Int index]
{
    get
    {
        var positionRelative = PositionToRelative(position);
        return data[VectorToIndex(positionRelative)];
    }
    set
    {
        var positionRelative = PositionToRelative(position);
        data[VectorToIndex(positionRelative)] = value;
    }
}
```

and/or even keep both for convenience

```
public T this[int x, int y, int z]
{
    get => this[new Vector3Int(x, y, z)];
    set => this[new Vector3Int(x, y, z)] = value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it pretty much works, however I want the last column to be all 0s, not to be wrapped around, and preferably call some kind of function with a List<Vector3Int> of all the positions that were set to 0